# Problem with CDK Drag and Drop Resizable (Angular)

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I've tried to resize an element with Angular CDK Drag and Drop, but I can't get it.

Somebody can help me? What do I need to do to achieve this result? I'm building a template similar to a report, where I can drag and drop fields inside the DIV HTML. But CDK D&D I can't get it to resize the component.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried those functionalities last year with angular 8
You can find example projects here. https://github.com/PushpikaWan/angular-drag-drop-rearrange

There are different mechanisms in different branches

- lib_1.0 - which has simple CDK drag and drop
- lib_2.0 - which has a material grid-related implementation
- lib_3.0 - which has native HTML event driven drag and drop implementation